# Security of streaming replication?

Tags: postgresql, security

If I want to use streaming replication between two Postgresql databases on different parts of the internet, is there a way to secure or encrypt the connection between the two? Or are there reasons other than security to not do that?

I'd like to prevent eavesdropping via a man-in-the-middle attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streaming replication in PostgreSQL uses the same security mechanisms as a normal frontend-backend connection.  So in order to encrypt the traffic, SSL should be used, and access control should be set up.

Alternatively, or additionally, consider a VPN of some kind.  PostgreSQL instances aren't really meant to be run facing the open internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `scp`.

Ensure that your local `postgres` user can ssh passwordlessly to your remote host (`ssh-keygen -t dsa`) and that its public key (`~postgres/.ssh/id_dsa.pub`) is included in the remote hosts authorized_keys files (`~postgres/.ssh/authorized_keys`). Once you (as `postgres` user) can ssh to the remote host, update the following in your `postgresql.conf`:

```
archive_command = 'cp %p /path_to/archive/%f'
```

to

```
archive_command = 'scp -C %p remote-host:/path_to/archive/%f'
```

The `-C` is for compressing the transfer, which is something you probably want. For further compression, you may use instead:

```
archive_command = 'xz -c9 %p | ssh remote-host ''xz -d > /path_to/archive/%f'''
```

Comment: That wouldn't be streaming replication. That's just WAL shipping, isn't it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name isn't streaming replication, WAL shipping with a stand-by server? I double checked in case I'm missing on some new feature but couldn't find anything else.

Comment: No. With streaming replication the WAL segments are sent directly to the slave through a regular connection, not by writing files.